# How to create a bottom navigation bar with Custom Painter in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, custom-painter

How can I create a bottom navigation bar with a `CustomPainter` like this?

[image: bottom navigation bar design]

Especially the `FloatingActionButton` notch / edges.

Update: I did it using custom `FloatingActionButtonLocation`

```dart
class CustomFABLocation extends FloatingActionButtonLocation {
  const CustomFABLocation({
    required this.bottomBarHeight,
  });

  final double bottomBarHeight;

  @override
  Offset getOffset(ScaffoldPrelayoutGeometry scaffoldGeometry) {
    final xPos = scaffoldGeometry.scaffoldSize.width * .4;
    final yPos = scaffoldGeometry.scaffoldSize.height - bottomBarHeight - 13.0;

    return Offset(xPos, yPos);
  }
}
```

Here is the result:

[image: result-bottom-app-bar]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: actually you can make it without a CustomPainter, if it's fine, I can help

Comment: @Gwhyyy thank you, I made it without CustomPainter

Answer (score 0):

You may like the style-15 of this package. Just apply padding to center button.

https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but i was trying to do it without using package.

Comment: copy that style code from repo of that package.